# `eval` using variable local to the function

Tags: r, eval

Sourcing this code:

```
a <- F
f1 <- function() a
f2 <- function() {
  a <- T
  eval(f1())
}
```

and calling `f2()` will return `FALSE`.

How to modify the arguments for the `eval` so that `f2()` will return `TRUE` ?

Comment: Specify arguments to functions explicitly and you will not bother with in which environment the function is executed and from where the arguments come from.

Comment: the reason why I cannot specify `f1` with `a` as argument is because my f1 is in fact `Ops.myclass`, which has `Ops(e1, e2)` signature, not `Ops(e1, e2, a)` signature. What I want to achieve is for Ops to operate on my class with different behaviors depending on value of `a`

Comment: In your example `a` is global, if it is in your real code as well you could assign a using `<<-` in `f2`.  Or use the `assign` function to a particular environment...

Comment: Since you control `myclass`, why don't you just add a slot to contain `a` and pass it that way, or even better, define different sub-classes that invoke different methods depending on what type of `a` they belong to?

Comment: @Thell I should have mentioned that that I would not want any accidentally defined "global" `a` clash with the behavior of `f2`, which depends on the local `a`

Comment: @BrodieG thanks, I will certainly reconsider. Had that solution in mind before, I thought I could end up with simpler code than that by switching `eval` scope.

Comment: Daniel, did my answer address below your original question?  I think it does.  If it doesn't please comment on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
a <- F
f1 <- function() a
f2 <- function() {
  a <- T
  environment(f1) <- new.env()
  eval(f1())
}
f2()
# [1] TRUE
```

Though I wouldn't encourage it.  What we've done here is changed the environment of `f1` to be one which has for enclosure `f2`'s environment, which means `f1` will have access to `f2`s variables through "lexical" scoping (well, faux-lexical here b/c we short circuited it).

Generally, as Roman suggests, you should explicitly pass arguments to functions as otherwise you can quickly run into trouble.

Comment: Thanks, I've learned something. For those interested, here is also more [background reading on scoping](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-scope.pdf)